# Cannot carry out Ajax request from wikipedia

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to use wikipedia API in my project to grab images of people, but fail. I use this url:`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&titles=Albert%20Einstein&pithumbsize=100`
When i console browser says the following

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&titles=Albe…Callback&callback=jQuery22409288979864744966_1470068280411&_=1470068280412' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

My code

```
var general = {
    // The URL to the quote API
    url: 'http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/',
    // What to display as the author name if s/he's unknown
    unknownAuthor: 'Uknown',
    // Base URL for the tweet links generation
    tweetURL: 'http://twitter.com/home?status=',
    wikiURL:'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&titles=Albert Einstein&pithumbsize=100&callback=wikiCallback'
};

var wikirequest = function() {
    $.ajax({
      url:general.wikiURL,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(wikData) {
      console.log(wikData);
      //var image = wikiData.
      displayQuote(image);
      } // end of success
    });
}// wikirequest

wikirequest();
```

[Pen](http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/YWjALR)

Has anyone met the same issue?

Comment: What are you typing into the console?

Comment: I will edit my question and will answer you thanks btw

Comment: Please paste code and errors in `code blocks` rather than using images.

Comment: Done! Thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to load the data using JSONP, but you are making a request to a URL that returns an HTML document. JSONP requests have to be answered with JavaScript programs (since that is a fundamental feature of how they work … and also why they are dangerous and should be avoided in favour of plain JSON and CORS).

To make it return JSONP you need to provided two additional query string parameters:

- `format=json`
- `callback=YourCallbackName`

… where `YourCallbackName` is the name of the function that should be executed and passed the data you are fetching as an argument. Most Ajax libraries will generate that name (and the function itself) dynamically when you specify `callback=?`.

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer!

Comment: By the way i want to fetch images from this request, the problem is the object provides images with different ids so it is impossible to get them because they changes depending on the name. Can you suggest me a way out of this issue?

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&titles=Albert%20Einstein&pithumbsize=100&format=json

You are missing the &format=json on the URL - The page was displaying the data with the html header and you would have been attempting to decode this. The above answer is actually better.

Comment: Appreciate your helpful answer!